# Unable to see whether creating type in Oracle successfully

Tags: oracle, types

everybody

I got a problem that when I try to create a type at my local oracle database.
the following script had been run on server successfully

```
CREATE OR REPLACE TYPE EEP.Members AS OBJECT 
(
        id                         VARCHAR2(6),        
        name                       VARCHAR2(14),               
        email                      VARCHAR2(4)
)
/
```

and it can also be run successfully at local oracle, the problem is the type I would like to create still can not be found even statue shows "type created complete"

I can not turn the options on(usually click a "plus" to see more detail) at the place I can see all types, I have no idea whether is privileges problem or any problem else..

I will need to do some program examination in my laptop, not I am stocked by this problem...

Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use

```
DESC type_name;
```

to describe types.

To see all the available types in your system, you can run

```
SELECT *
FROM user_objects
WHERE object_type = 'TYPE'
;
```